# Simplify Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K}) $  (where $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} \} $) invertible matrices such that $A + B = I_n$  (where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$). Solve the following equation for $X$.

$$ A^2XB^T + (BX^TB^TA^T)^T = BAB^T $$

I started by doing the following

$ A^2XB^T + (BX^TB^TA^T)^T = BAB^T \iff A^2XB^T + ABXB^T = BAB^T \iff$

$ \iff (A^2X + ABX)B^T = BAB^T \iff A^2X + ABX = BA \iff$

$ \iff (A^2 + AB)X = BA \iff X = (A^2+AB)^{-1}BA$

But I sense that this is not the simplest answer.
Any hints on how to simplify this?

Best regards

Comment: You can still use that $A+B=I$, i.e., $A^2+AB=A$. Then $X=A^{-1}BA$, which is simple enough.

Comment: Note that $B = I - A$, so that
$$
BA = (I - A)A = A - A^2 = A(I - A) = AB.
$$
With that and the other comment, we have
$$
X = A^{-1}BA = A^{-1}AB = B.
$$

Comment: Thank you both, I forgot to mark the question as answered.